# apache redirect everything except certain paths

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect

Brand new to apache, using 2.4 in this case, trying to get a redirect rule to work such that everything on port 80 is redirected to 443, except certain routes.

This rule keeps redirecting everything even the path i specified.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName some-name
        ServerAdmin some-name
        UseCanonicalName on
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "! /server-status/*"
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://some-name$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need modify the RewriteCond, this because the REQUEST_URI includes everything after and including the forward slash.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/server-status/
REQUEST_URI = /server-status/
```

The `^` mean defines that the patter must start at beginning of a new line and `.*` finds any character sequence.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName some-name
        ServerAdmin some-name
        UseCanonicalName on
        RewriteEngine On

        # Modify this line
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/server-status/.*"

        # You can remove this line           
        # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://some-name$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```